# BitArray alternative for the .NET Micro Framework

Tags: .net, .net-micro-framework, bitarray

Is there a BitArray alternative for the .NET Micro Framework?
I was thinking about simply using a bool[], but how can you convert it back
into a byte[] ?

In the full framework, considering "bits" is a BitArray, the following works:

```
byte[] data = new byte[dimensions / 8];
bits.CopyTo(data, 0);
```

But I cannot seem to find the BitArray class in the micro framework

Comment: What exactly do you need? Maybe a `byte` which you can manipulate is enough?

Comment: BitArray is implemented using integers and bitwise operators

Comment: @Bobby nope really needed to operate at the bit level :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not terribly difficult to duplicate the functionality of `BitArray`.  First, if you need fewer than 65 bits, then you can do it with a `long` or smaller.

To set an individual bit:

```
void Set(ref long ba, int bit)
{
    ba |= 1L << bit;
}
```

To clear a bit:

```
void Clear(ref long ba, int bit)
{
    long mask = 1L << bit;
    mask = ~mask;
    ba &= mask;
}
```

To see if a bit is set:

```
bool IsSet(long ba, int bit)
{
    long mask = 1L << bit;
    return (ba & mask) != 0;
}
```

If you have more than 64 bits, then you'll need to create an array (`byte[]`, probably), and do the division to determine which byte/bit you want to modify.  The methods above will work, provided you change the `long` to `byte`.

For example, if you have:

```
byte[] myBytes = new byte[128];
```

You have 1024 bits.

To set a bit:

```
void Set (int bit)
{
    int byte = bit/8;
    int bitIndex = bit%8;
    myBytes[byte] |= (byte)(1 << bitIndex);
}
```

The other methods use the same math to get the byte and bit index, and setting, clearing, and testing a bit is the same as with the `long` example above.

Comment: If `Interlocked.CompareExchange` is available on the micro framework, one could use that to make any desired types of bit operations atomic.  Within a loop, read the old value of the word, compute a new value, and `CompareExchange` the old value to the new one; reloop until the `CompareExchange` succeeds.  I personally like having an atomic method to compute `Thebits = (TheBits & ~Mask) ^ NewBits)`.  Bits which are clear in `Mask` and `NewBits` are left alone; those that are clear in `Mask` and set in `NewBits` are toggled.  Bits that are set in `Mask` will be copied from `NewBits`.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a BitArray Implementation in the 802.15.4 Stack. Just search the Porting Kit for BitArray.cs

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded an array for .net microframework:

http://code.tinyclr.com/project/310/bitarray-class/

Hope this helps.