# What is the C# equivalent of std::bitset of C++

Tags: c#, c++

What is the C# equivalent of `std::bitset` of C++?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There are a few options, including [BitVector32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx), and [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx).

Comment: The difference being that `BitVector32` is more efficient at the cost of being limited to 32-bits, whereas `BitArray` will grow as needed at the cost of overhead.

Answer (score 9):

Another option, if you want up to 64 bits but you don't want the overhead of a `BitArray`, is to put together your own `BitVector64` using the samples from [BitArray alternative for the .NET Micro Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107039/bitarray-alternative-for-the-net-micro-framework/4107287#4107287).

Comment: Rather than add another answer to this ancient question, I will just mention that you can actually take this even further using unsafe code and fixed size buffers.  You can create a struct that holds a compile-time constant number of ulong, for example, and then write your own methods and operators that perform bitwise operations against them.  I have done this, and it worked well enough for me.  There is no heap allocation, and copying is as easy as basic assignment, just like any other struct.