# What is the C# equivalent of BitSet of Java?

Tags: c#, java, bitset

My requirements are simple:

1. Be able to define dimensions of bit array, i.e: 5 bytes.
2. bool Get(bitIndex: int)
3. Set(bitIndex: int)

Is there a c# equivalent which provides similar functionality to `BitSet` in Java?

Here's the scenario:

1. Initialize 5 bytes, all bits are 0(false).
2. Set byte 3, bit 8 to TRUE.
3. Get status of byte 3, bit 8.

**UPDATE**: Solution from Michael Bray:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
  // Set for 5 bytes 
  BitArray ba = new BitArray(8 * 5); 

  // Set bit #1 on byte #4 
  ba.Set(GetBitNum(4, 1), true); 

  // Get bit #1 on byte #4 
  bool v = ba.Get(GetBitNum(4, 1)); 
} 

static int GetBitNum(int byteNum, int bitNum)   // Assumes index starts at 1 
{ 
  return (byteNum - 1) * 8 + (bitNum - 1); 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144349/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-stdbitset-of-c might help

Comment: @mfrankli I have looked into that question before I opened this:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`System.Collections.BitArray` is pretty close, but it's a bit lacking in features.  I wrote a helper class that implements a lot of features you might need for BitArray some time ago, but I'd have to dig it up.  Let me know if you think you need it.

**EDIT**: As requested in the comments below, I've posted the code at http://pastebin.com/GLyzcUZC.  As I discuss, though, it's benefits over stock BitArray are minimal, as I wrote it for some specific needs that I had.  Do with it as you wish.

**EDIT 2**: As Miguel pointed out in the comments, there are some implementation issues that make my 'BitArray' code not so good...  I had already realized the deficiencies and had re-written a new version called BoolArray (to distinguish from BitArray) that doesn't suffer from those problems :

```
namespace Utils
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading;

    /// <summary>
    /// A replacement for BitArray
    /// </summary>
    public class BoolArray : IEnumerable, ICollection, ICloneable
    {
        private UInt32[] bits = null;
        private int _length = 0;
        private static UInt32 ONE = (UInt32)1 << 31;
        private object _syncRoot;
        private static Func<byte[], byte[]> EndianFixer = null;

        #region Constructors

        static BoolArray()
        {
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) EndianFixer = (a) => a.Reverse().ToArray();
            else EndianFixer = (a) => a;
        }

        public BoolArray(BoolArray srcBits)
        {
            this.InitializeFrom(srcBits.ToArray());
        }

        public BoolArray(BitArray srcBits)
        {
            this._length = srcBits.Count;
            this.bits = new UInt32[RequiredSize(this._length)];

            for (int i = 0; i < srcBits.Count; i++) this[i] = srcBits[i];
        }

        public BoolArray(int v)
        {
            ICollection<byte> bytes = EndianFixer(BitConverter.GetBytes(v)).ToList();
            InitializeFrom(bytes);
        }

        public BoolArray(ICollection<bool> srcBits)
        {
            this.InitializeFrom(srcBits.ToArray());
        }

        public BoolArray(ICollection<byte> srcBits)
        {
            InitializeFrom(srcBits);
        }

        public BoolArray(ICollection<short> srcBits)
        {
            ICollection<byte> bytes = srcBits.SelectMany(v => EndianFixer(BitConverter.GetBytes(v))).ToList();
            InitializeFrom(bytes);
        }

        public BoolArray(ICollection<ushort> srcBits)
        {
            ICollection<byte> bytes = srcBits.SelectMany(v => EndianFixer(BitConverter.GetBytes(v))).ToList();
            InitializeFrom(bytes);
        }

        public BoolArray(ICollection<int> srcBits)
        {
            ICollection<byte> bytes = srcBits.SelectMany(v => EndianFixer(BitConverter.GetBytes(v))).ToList();
            InitializeFrom(bytes);
        }

        public BoolArray(ICollection<uint> srcBits)
        {
            ICollection<byte> bytes = srcBits.SelectMany(v => EndianFixer(BitConverter.GetBytes(v))).ToList();
            InitializeFrom(bytes);
        }

        public BoolArray(ICollection<long> srcBits)
        {
            ICollection<byte> bytes = srcBits.SelectMany(v => EndianFixer(BitConverter.GetBytes(v))).ToList();
            InitializeFrom(bytes);
        }

        public BoolArray(ICollection<ulong> srcBits)
        {
            ICollection<byte> bytes = srcBits.SelectMany(v => EndianFixer(BitConverter.GetBytes(v))).ToList();
            InitializeFrom(bytes);
        }

        public BoolArray(int capacity, bool defaultValue = false)
        {
            this.bits = new UInt32[RequiredSize(capacity)];
            this._length = capacity;

            // Only need to do this if true, because default for all bits is false
            if (defaultValue) for (int i = 0; i < this._length; i++) this[i] = true;
        }

        private void InitializeFrom(ICollection<byte> srcBits)
        {
            this._length = srcBits.Count * 8;
            this.bits = new UInt32[RequiredSize(this._length)];
            for (int i = 0; i < srcBits.Count; i++)
            {
                uint bv = srcBits.Skip(i).Take(1).Single();
                for (int b = 0; b < 8; b++)
                {
                    bool bitVal = ((bv << b) & 0x0080) != 0;
                    int bi = 8 * i + b;
                    this[bi] = bitVal;
                }
            }
        }

        private void InitializeFrom(ICollection<bool> srcBits)
        {
            this._length = srcBits.Count;
            this.bits = new UInt32[RequiredSize(this._length)];

            int index = 0;
            foreach (var b in srcBits) this[index++] = b;
        }

        private static int RequiredSize(int bitCapacity)
        {
            return (bitCapacity + 31) >> 5;
        }

        #endregion

        public bool this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                if (index >= _length) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

                int byteIndex = index >> 5;
                int bitIndex = index & 0x1f;
                return ((bits[byteIndex] << bitIndex) & ONE) != 0;
            }
            set
            {
                if (index >= _length) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

                int byteIndex = index >> 5;
                int bitIndex = index & 0x1f;
                if (value) bits[byteIndex] |= (ONE >> bitIndex);
                else bits[byteIndex] &= ~(ONE >> bitIndex);
            }
        }

        #region Interfaces implementation
        #region IEnumerable
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            //for (int i = 0; i < _length; i++) yield return this[i];
            return this.ToArray().GetEnumerator();
        }
        #endregion
        #region ICollection
        public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
        {
            if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
            if (index < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
            if (array.Rank != 1) throw new ArgumentException("Multidimensional array not supported");
            if (array is UInt32[]) Array.Copy(this.bits, 0, array, index, (this.Count + sizeof(UInt32) - 1) / sizeof(UInt32));
            else if (array is bool[]) Array.Copy(this.ToArray(), 0, array, index, this.Count);
            else throw new ArgumentException("Array type not supported (UInt32[] or bool[] only)");

        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return this._length; }
            private set
            {
                if (value > this._length) Extend(value - this._length);
                else this._length = Math.Max(0, value);
            }
        }

        public bool IsSynchronized
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public object SyncRoot
        {
            get
            {
                if (this._syncRoot == null) Interlocked.CompareExchange<object>(ref this._syncRoot, new object(), null);
                return _syncRoot;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region ICloneable
        public object Clone()
        {
            return new BoolArray(this);
        }
        // Not part of ICloneable, but better - returns a strongly-typed result
        public BoolArray Dup()
        {
            return new BoolArray(this);
        }
        #endregion 
        #endregion

        #region String Conversions

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ToBinaryString();
            //return ToHexString(" ", " ■ ");
        }

        public static BoolArray FromHexString(string hex)
        {
            if (hex == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("hex");

            List<bool> bits = new List<bool>();
            for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i++)
            {
                int b = byte.Parse(hex[i].ToString(), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                bits.Add((b >> 3) == 1);
                bits.Add(((b & 0x7) >> 2) == 1);
                bits.Add(((b & 0x3) >> 1) == 1);
                bits.Add((b & 0x1) == 1);
            }
            BoolArray ba = new BoolArray(bits.ToArray());
            return ba;
        }

        public string ToHexString(string bitSep8 = null, string bitSep128 = null)
        {
            string s = string.Empty;
            int b = 0;
            bool[] bbits = this.ToArray();

            for (int i = 1; i <= bbits.Length; i++)
            {
                b = (b << 1) | (bbits[i - 1] ? 1 : 0);
                if (i % 4 == 0)
                {
                    s = s + string.Format("{0:x}", b);
                    b = 0;
                }

                if (i % (8 * 16) == 0)
                {
                    s = s + bitSep128;
                }
                else if (i % 8 == 0)
                {
                    s = s + bitSep8;
                }
            }
            int ebits = bbits.Length % 4;
            if (ebits != 0)
            {
                b = b << (4 - ebits);
                s = s + string.Format("{0:x}", b);
            }
            return s;
        }

        public static BoolArray FromBinaryString(string bin, char[] trueChars = null)
        {
            if (trueChars == null) trueChars = new char[] { '1', 'Y', 'y', 'T', 't' };
            if (bin == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("bin");
            BoolArray ba = new BoolArray(bin.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < bin.Length; i++) ba[i] = bin[i].In(trueChars);
            return ba;
        }

        public string ToBinaryString(char setChar = '1', char unsetChar = '0')
        {
            return new string(this.ToArray().Select(v => v ? setChar : unsetChar).ToArray());
        }

        #endregion

        #region Class Methods
        public bool[] ToArray()
        {
            bool[] vbits = new bool[this._length];
            for (int i = 0; i < _length; i++) vbits[i] = this[i];
            return vbits;
        }

        public BoolArray Append(ICollection<bool> addBits)
        {
            int startPos = this._length;
            Extend(addBits.Count);
            bool[] bitArray = addBits.ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < bitArray.Length; i++) this[i + startPos] = bitArray[i];
            return this;
        }

        public BoolArray Append(BoolArray addBits)
        {
            return this.Append(addBits.ToArray());
        }

        public static BoolArray Concatenate(params BoolArray[] bArrays)
        {
            return new BoolArray(bArrays.SelectMany(ba => ba.ToArray()).ToArray());
        }

        private void Extend(int numBits)
        {
            numBits += this._length;
            int reqBytes = RequiredSize(numBits);
            if (reqBytes > this.bits.Length)
            {
                UInt32[] newBits = new UInt32[reqBytes];
                this.bits.CopyTo(newBits, 0);
                this.bits = newBits;
            }
            this._length = numBits;
        }

        public bool Get(int index)
        {
            return this[index];
        }

        public BoolArray GetBits(int startBit = 0, int numBits = -1)
        {
            if (numBits == -1) numBits = bits.Length;
            return new BoolArray(this.ToArray().Skip(startBit).Take(numBits).ToArray());
        }

        public BoolArray Repeat(int numReps)
        {
            bool[] oBits = this.ToArray();
            List<bool> nBits = new List<bool>();
            for(int i=0; i<numReps; i++) nBits.AddRange(oBits);
            this.InitializeFrom(nBits);
            return this;
        }

        public BoolArray Reverse()
        {
            int n = this.Count;
            for(int i=0; i<n/2; i++) 
            {
                bool b1 = this[i];
                this[i] = this[n - i - 1];
                this[n - i - 1] = b1;
            }
            return this;
        }

        public BoolArray Set(int index, bool v)
        {
            this[index] = v;
            return this;
        }

        public BoolArray SetAll(bool v)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++) this[i] = v;
            return this;
        }

        public BoolArray SetBits(ICollection<bool> setBits, int destStartBit = 0, int srcStartBit = 0, int numBits = -1, bool allowExtend = false)
        {
            if (setBits == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("setBits");
            if ((destStartBit < 0) || (destStartBit >= this.Count)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("destStartBit");
            if ((srcStartBit < 0) || (srcStartBit >= setBits.Count)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("srcStartBit");

            bool[] sBits;
            if (setBits is bool[]) sBits = (bool[])setBits;
            else sBits = setBits.ToArray();

            if (numBits == -1) numBits = setBits.Count;
            if (numBits > (setBits.Count - srcStartBit)) numBits = setBits.Count - srcStartBit;

            int diffSize = numBits - (this.Count - destStartBit);
            if (diffSize > 0)
            {
                if (allowExtend) Extend(diffSize);
                else numBits = this.Count - destStartBit;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < numBits; i++) this[destStartBit + i] = sBits[srcStartBit + i];
            return this;
        }

        public List<BoolArray> SplitEvery(int numBits)
        {
            int i = 0;
            List<BoolArray> bitSplits = new List<BoolArray>();
            while (i < this.Count)
            {
                bitSplits.Add(this.GetBits(i, numBits));
                i += numBits;
            }
            return bitSplits;
        }

        public byte[] ToBytes(int startBit = 0, int numBits = -1)
        {
            if (numBits == -1) numBits = this._length - startBit;
            BoolArray ba = GetBits(startBit, numBits);
            int nb = (numBits + 7) / 8;
            byte[] bb = new byte[nb];
            for (int i = 0; i < ba.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!ba[i]) continue;
                int bp = 7 - (i % 8);
                bb[i / 8] = (byte)((int)bb[i / 8] | (1 << bp));
            }
            return bb;
        }


        #endregion

        #region Logical Bitwise Operations
        public BoolArray BinaryBitwiseOp(Func<bool, bool, bool> op, BoolArray ba, int start = 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ba.Count; i++)
            {
                if (start + i >= this.Count) break;
                this[start + i] = op(this[start + i], ba[i]);
            }
            return this;
        }

        public BoolArray Xor(BoolArray xor, int start = 0)
        {
            return BinaryBitwiseOp((a, b) => (a ^ b), xor, start);
        }

        public BoolArray And(BoolArray and, int start = 0)
        {
            return BinaryBitwiseOp((a, b) => (a & b), and, start);
        }

        public BoolArray Or(BoolArray or, int start = 0)
        {
            return BinaryBitwiseOp((a, b) => (a | b), or, start);
        }

        public BoolArray Not(int start = 0, int len = -1)
        {
            for (int i = start; i < this.Count; i++)
            {
                if (--len == -1) break;
                this[i] = !this[i];
            }
            return this;
        } 
        #endregion

        #region Class Operators

        public static BoolArray operator +(BoolArray a, BoolArray b)
        {
            return a.Dup().Append(b);
        }

        public static BoolArray operator |(BoolArray a, BoolArray b)
        {
            return a.Dup().Or(b);
        }

        public static BoolArray operator &(BoolArray a, BoolArray b)
        {
            return a.Dup().And(b);
        }

        public static BoolArray operator ^(BoolArray a, BoolArray b)
        {
            return a.Dup().Xor(b);
        }

        public static BoolArray operator ~(BoolArray a)
        {
            return a.Dup().Not();
        }

        public static BoolArray operator <<(BoolArray a, int shift)
        {
            return a.Dup().Append(new bool[shift]);
        }

        public static BoolArray operator >>(BoolArray a, int shift)
        {
            return new BoolArray(a.ToArray().Take(Math.Max(0, a.Count - shift)).ToArray());
        }

        public static bool operator ==(BoolArray a, BoolArray b)
        {
            if (a.Count != b.Count) return false;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++) if (a[i] != b[i]) return false;
            return true;
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (!(obj is BoolArray)) return false;
            return (this == (BoolArray)obj);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.ToHexString().GetHashCode();
        }

        public static bool operator !=(BoolArray a, BoolArray b)
        {
            return !(a == b);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this is not a message board, you should assume one-way communication: either provide the additional info, or not offer to provide it on request.

Comment: Funny, though, I do get notifications when people respond in comments to my answers.  I do make a best effort to respond to such comments, as I have yours.  A simple request in the comments will suffice for this person, if they want it.

Comment: I think that *was* a request :)

Comment: @MichaelBray Appreciated that :) Does BitArray(C#) Get and Set works the similar output as Java's BitSet? If you are able to dig it up, its great if you could share it here :) I'm sure it could benefit the others .

Comment: You do get notifications when people respond, but since the site has so much visibility, someone else will discover your answer sooner or later who may have different requirements than the OP. If you put the info in, you'd get another upvote from him; if you do not put the info in, there would be a near dupe on the site, or a notification with a request for more info six month down the road :):):)

Comment: @Roylee, yes - there is both Get() and Set() methods that return bool, along with other functions.  Here's the reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx.  I'm also trying to dig my code up now - having a bit of trouble, though, it's not where I thought it was.  :(

Comment: @MichaelBray I saw that too :) But I'm not sure as the Get in BitArray works as BitSet, as in BitSet, its accepting bitIndex.

Comment: I found the code - posted to PasteBin: http://pastebin.com/GLyzcUZC  But looking at it now I'm not sure how much better it is compared to stock.  I wrote it for the online Coursera Crypto class, but I must have had some specific needs because it doesn't seem all that much more functional.  Anyway, it's there to look at if you want to use it.

Comment: @MichaelBray using BitArray, are you able to demo, 5 bytes, first SET true to byte2, bit 8; and secondly, GET status of byte4, bit 1. :) Would greatly appreciated if you could provide some demo.

Comment: @Roylee: Which BitArray - stock or my custom version?

Comment: @MichaelBray the predefined BitArray in C#, can it be done? :) Or only your custom version could do that? You could use any methods as long as it works :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21696/discussion-between-michael-bray-and-roylee)

Comment: I don't know how this post was mark as the answer for the question. The post text is good and i agree with that, but the implementation posted in http://pastebin.com/GLyzcUZC have many design issues.

1- The implementation use bool[] as store for values, this is not a good idea. The main purpose of the BitSets is the store of huge amount of bit values allocating less memory than the bool[].

2- The second thing is that the bitset implementation use the bit operation (& | ~) to improve the performance of many operations.

Comment: Miguel, I agree with your points.  As it happens, I already updated my own code to address these points.  Here's a newer version (now called BoolArray to distinguish from BitArray) that uses UInt32 for internal storage, and also provides operator overloads for the bitwise functions.  http://pastebin.com/m4yp4vGs

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but had more than just the one Cardinality method to convert. So, I opted to port the entire BitSet class. Fortunately it was self-contained.

Here is [the Gist of the C# port](https://gist.github.com/NightOwl888/12abed2c1a68330ac57d).

I have also added it to the open source [BoboBrowse.Net project](https://github.com/NightOwl888/BoboBrowse.Net/blob/master/src/BoboBrowse.Net/BoboBrowse.Net/Support/BitSet.cs).

I have also ported the version from Apache Harmony (which is essentially a carbon copy of the JDK) and added it to the general library [J2N](https://www.nuget.org/packages/J2N) so it is easy to consume.

Comment: Off topic: Do any guidance on porting Java to C#? Other than 'copy paste translate' (I'm on twitter with same name, if you want to take off line, so to speak)