# Storing multiple values via bitmask in c#

Tags: c#, bitmask, bit-masks

I'm trying to store four independent 5-bit values (0-31) inside a 32-bit int via bit mask but am having trouble getting the values correct to set and get the individual values from the masked int used for storage.

Can anyone help me with this?

Edit:

Sorry for the external link - here's some JavaScript demonstrating what I'm trying to achieve (but in bitmasks instead of decimal algebra):

```
var s = 0;

var v = [31, 6, 23, 31];

//save values
s = v[0] + (v[1] * 32) + (v[2] * 1024) + (v[3] * 32768);

console.log(s);

//retrieve values
v[3] = parseInt(s / 32768);
v[2] = parseInt((s - (v[3] * 32768)) / 1024);
v[1] = parseInt((s - ((v[3] * 32768) + (v[2] * 1024))) / 32);
v[0] = parseInt(s - ((v[3] * 32768)+ (v[2] * 1024) + (v[1] * 32)));

console.log(v);

//modify values [1] and [2]
s = s - (v[1] * 32) + (9 * 32);
s = s - (v[2] * 1024) + (17 * 1024);

console.log(s);

//retrieve values
v[3] = parseInt(s / 32768);
v[2] = parseInt((s - (v[3] * 32768)) / 1024);
v[1] = parseInt((s - ((v[3] * 32768) + (v[2] * 1024))) / 32);
v[0] = parseInt(s - ((v[3] * 32768)+ (v[2] * 1024) + (v[1] * 32)));

console.log(v);
```

Output:

```
1039583
[31, 6, 23, 31]
1033535
[31, 9, 17, 31]
```

Edit:

Thanks to Peter Duniho I was able to make these with the masks build in to save some operations for 6 5-bit values inside a 32-bit integer:

```
uint Get_5_In_32(uint storage, int index)
{
    switch (index)
    {
        case 0:
            return (storage & 0x0000001F);
        case 1:
            return (storage & 0x000003E0) >> 5;
        case 2:
            return (storage & 0x00007C00) >> 10;
        case 3:
            return (storage & 0x000F8000) >> 15;
        case 4:
            return (storage & 0x01F00000) >> 20;
        case 5:
            return (storage & 0x3E000000) >> 25;
        default:
            return (0);
    }
}
uint Set_5_In_32(uint storage, uint value, int index)
{
    if (value > 31) {  value = 31; }
    switch (index)
    {
        case 0:
            return (storage & 0xFFFFFFE0) | value;
        case 1:
            return (storage & 0xFFFFFC1F) | (value << 5);
        case 2:
            return (storage & 0xFFFF83FF) | (value << 10);
        case 3:
            return (storage & 0xFFF07FFF) | (value << 15);
        case 4:
            return (storage & 0xFE0FFFFF) | (value << 20);
        case 5:
            return (storage & 0xC1FFFFFF) | (value << 25);
        default:
            return (0);
    }
}
```

And a byref version of the Set function for even less allocation:

```
void Set_5_In_32(ref uint storage, uint value, int index)
{
    if (value > 31) {  value = 31; }
    switch (index)
    {
        case 0:
            storage &= 0xFFFFFFE0;
            storage |= value;
            break;
        case 1:
            storage &= 0xFFFFFC1F;
            storage |= (value << 5);
            break;
        case 2:
            storage &= 0xFFFF83FF;
            storage |= (value << 10);
            break;
        case 3:
            storage &= 0xFFF07FFF;
            storage |= (value << 15);
            break;
        case 4:
            storage &= 0xFE0FFFFF;
            storage |= (value << 20);
            break;
        case 5:
            storage &= 0xC1FFFFFF;
            storage |= (value << 25);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the C# equivalent of BitSet of Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035687/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-bitset-of-java)

Comment: No, basically what I'm trying to achieve would be a c# equivalent of https://jsfiddle.net/mj28pk8f/1/ but without the overhead of the arithmetic (this needs to be running very fast and since bitmasks would be the fastest it could get that's what I need to use).  An external BitArray class is too much overhead.

Comment: I don't know JavaScript well enough to know whether the code you have is the best way to do it in that language. However, the code I posted in my answer will accomplish the same thing, in what is IMHO a simpler, more readable, more general way.

Comment: Your code would be more readable when you'd swap the order of shifts and masks since in that case the mask would always be `0x1F`.

Comment: Thanks - that works on the Get function but is there a specific mask I'd need to get that working on the Set function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a more specific question, and in particular you showing the code you have so far and explaining what you're having trouble *specifically* in terms of getting it to work, it's hard to know exactly what the best answer would be.

That said, here are a couple of example methods that might get you pointed in the right direction:

```
// Stores the given value in storage at the given index
int Set(int storage, int value, int index)
{
    int shiftCount = index * 5,
        mask = 0x1f << shiftCount;

    return (storage & ~mask) | (value << shiftCount);
}

// Retrieves the value stored in storage at the given index
int Get(int storage, int index)
{
    int shiftCount = index * 5,
        mask = 0x1f << shiftCount;

    return (storage & mask) >> shiftCount;
}
```

The `Set()` method above takes the current value in `storage`, clears all of the bits in the range of bits where you want to store your five-bit value, and then uses the `|` operator to store that five-bit value, shifting the bits of that value to the right place first.

The `Get()` method performs the reverse operation. It masks off (clears) all of the bits *not* in the range of bits where the value was stored, and then shifting the stored bits down to the least-significant five bits of an `int` before returning that result.

Notes:

- The above is specific to your stated problem. It could easily be generalized by encapsulating in a class where the bit count can be configured at initialization and the mask is generated based on that bit count rather than being hard-coded.
- There is no error-checking in the above code. In a production-code version, it would be much better to verify that the `value` passed to the `Set()` method does in fact fit in five bits (i.e. is less than `0x20`).

**EDIT:**

Here is a simple console program that demonstrates the use of the above, with your example data:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = { 31, 6, 23, 31 };
    int storage = 0;

    storage = ArrayToStorage(array, storage);

    Console.WriteLine(storage);
    LogArray(array);

    storage = Set(storage, 9, 1);
    storage = Set(storage, 17, 2);

    StorageToArray(array, storage);

    Console.WriteLine(storage);
    LogArray(array);
}

static int ArrayToStorage(int[] array, int storage)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        storage = Set(storage, array[i], i);
    }

    return storage;
}

static void StorageToArray(int[] array, int storage)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = Get(storage, i);
    }
}

static void LogArray(int[] array)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[" + string.Join(", ", array) + "]");
}

// Stores the given value in storage at the given index
static int Set(int storage, int value, int index)
{
    int shiftCount = index * 5,
        mask = 0x1f << shiftCount;

    return (storage & ~mask) | (value << shiftCount);
}

// Retrieves the value stored in storage at the given index
static int Get(int storage, int index)
{
    int shiftCount = index * 5,
        mask = 0x1f << shiftCount;

    return (storage & mask) >> shiftCount;
}
```