# Best method to convert byte-array's elements to binary

Tags: c#, arrays, optimization, type-conversion

I am making a program where I have to read approx. 4,140,000 bytes in a single file 4mb (with hundreds of files to be read daily, which I stored in a `byte[]` array). Each of those bytes have to be converted to binary so that I may be able to access them on bit level. Currently, each time when the program needs to access a byte, it calls a function which converts that `arr[byteIndex]` into a binary string by executing following line:

```
return binary.Append(Convert.ToString(arr[byteIndex], 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
```

The function is called millions of times. I want to make the program run faster. What is the best method/procedure I can use for time optimization.

Comment: a byte is already a binary value

Comment: yes but when i access it...e.g FF, it would give me "F" rather than "11111111", that is why i have to convert it to a binary string

Comment: Do you know `&` and `|` ? You don't need anything else for bit access.

Comment: I dont understand...please elaborate

Comment: You asked how to make your program run faster. Don't operate on a string representation of your bytes, either use bitwise logic to operate on the bits you need, or use a bitset like data structure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144349/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-stdbitset-of-c

Comment: i see...it didnt come to my mind...i'll try that now...thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working on the string representation, work on bits directly.

If your array value is `5A`, testing bit 4 can be done so:

```
if ((arr[byteIndex] & (1 << 4)) != 0) { }
```

Explaination:

```
arr[byteIndex] = 01011010
1<<4           = 00010000
                 -------- bitwise &
result         = 00010000
```