# Rewriting C++ algo to C# using BitArray

Tags: c#, operators, bitarray

I have the following code in C

```
        std::bitset < 80 > license;
        for (i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 32; j++)
            {
                if (CDKeyCopy[i] == TranslateTable[0][j])
                {
                    license <<= 5;
                    license |= j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (j == 32) //not found in TranslateTable
                return BADCDKEYCHAR;
        }
```

And I want to do the following in C#

```
            BitArray license = new BitArray(80);
            for (i = 15; i >= 4; i--)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 32; j++)
                {
                    if (licValue[i] == year[j])
                    {
                        license <<= 5;
                        license |= j;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //not found in TranslateTable
                if (j == 32)
                {
                    return LicenseInfos.BADCDKEYCHAR;
                }
            }
```

and I get the following error
error CS0019: Operator '<<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'BitArray' and 'int'
I want to be able to shift the value to the left and set it, as it does in c++.  I have search the web for hours without any luck, anyone can help me?

Comment: Looks like you want to left shift the BitArray, right? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684002/bitarray-shift-bits

Comment: I think you might not be searching well enough. My first search turned up a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use bit shift operator like that on bit array cause 
bitarray is not exact replacement of bitset

here are some info 
[What is the C# equivalent of std::bitset of C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144349/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-stdbitset-of-c)

[BitArray - Shift bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684002/bitarray-shift-bits)

Answer (score 0):

The shift operators are not implemented for BitArray in C#. See [Shifting a BitArray](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25596796/173225) for a possible implementation.

Rather than doing a straight port, why not take advantage of some of the features of .Net?

e.g. (not tested and taking a wild guess at the purpose of some variables, but gives the general idea):

```
var licValue = new List<int> { ... };
var years = new List<int> { ... }; // 32 years listed
int lic = 0;

...

if (licValue.Any(y => !years.Contains(y))) return LicenseInfos.BADCDKEYCHAR;

for (i = 15; i >= 4; i--)
{
    // lic <<= 5 then license |= index of year array 
    lic *= 32 + years.IndexOf(years.Where(y => licValue[i] == y).First());
}

// convert int to BitArray
var licenseArray = new BitArray(lic.PadLeft(80, '0')
    .ToCharArray().Select(b => b == '1' ? true : false).ToArray());
```