# C# StructLayout Pack=?? for use with bool values

Tags: c#, boolean, pack, structlayout

In C#, I am creating multiple different structs that contain 16 variables of type bool. I will have several different of these structs that will then be combined with  other data types into more complex structs.
I am needing to have them treated as being 2 bytes in length. In the code below, a variable created of type CtrlWord1 will give a length of 64 when I do a Marshal.SizeOf regardless of whether it is created with a Pack value of 0, 1 or 2.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct CtrlWord1
{
    public bool a1;
    public bool a2;
    public bool a3;
    public bool a4;
    public bool a5;
    public bool a6;
    public bool a7;
    public bool a8;
    public bool b1;
    public bool b2;
    public bool b3;
    public bool b4;
    public bool c1;
    public bool c2;
    public bool c3;
    public bool c4;
}
```

Comment: Packing/layout is done at the byte level. That means a bool will never take less than a byte relying purely on packing. You'll have to do something a little more involved, such as use two private byte fields and multiple properties which refer to the appropriate bits within those bytes.

Comment: You could use a [BitVector32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx) to get it down to 32 bits. Or, you could use the technique I describe in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107039/bitarray-alternative-for-the-net-micro-framework/4107287#, but use `ushort` rather than `long`.

Answer (score 2):

Although the `bool` type in C# is only 1 byte in size (`sizeof(bool) == 1`), the CLR defaults to marshalling it as the unmanaged `BOOL` type. This is the size you get when you call `Marshal.SizeOf`.

`BOOL` is a typedef in the Windows SDK headers for an `int`, which is 4 bytes in size. Why? Because these headers were written for the C language at a time that this language did not have a first-class Boolean type. It does now, but the decisions are fixed in stone for backwards-compatibility reasons. The CLR marshals `bool` types this way in order to be compatible with Windows API functions that use `BOOL` values, since interop with the Windows API is the most common usage of P/Invoke. (The same reason that the default calling convention for P/Invoke signatures is stdcall instead of cdecl.)

To tell the CLR to treat your `bool`s as 1-byte bools, rather than 4-byte `BOOL`s, use the [`MarshalAs` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx). Unfortunately, you have to use it 16 times:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct CtrlWord1
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]  // marshal as a 1-byte signed int, not a 4-byte BOOL
    public bool a1;

    // etc.
}
```

This will ensure that your struct is only 16 bytes.

However, there's no magic attribute to generate a bitfield. You'll have to create and manage this yourself using the `Int32` type. Or use the `BitArray` type.

Comment: That will give him a 16 byte struct, he is looking for a 2 byte bitfield.

Comment: The problem with `BitArray` is that it allocates an array, which incurs allocation overhead (12 or 24 bytes), plus 20 or 30 bytes of array overhead.

Answer (score 0):

[Glorin Oakenfoot said it much better than I could](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251727/c-sharp-structlayout-pack-for-use-with-bool-values#comment65839282_39251727), so I will just quote him

> Packing/layout is done at the byte level. That means a bool will never take less than a byte relying purely on packing. You'll have to do something a little more involved, such as use two private byte fields and multiple properties which refer to the appropriate bits within those bytes.

Here is a implementation of that, each item you increment the right hand side of the `1 << _` to move to the next bit field.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct CtrlWord1
{
    private Int16 _backingField;

    private void SetBitfield(Int16 mask, bool value)
    {
        if (value)
        {
            _backingField = (Int16)(_backingField | mask);
        }
        else
        {
            _backingField = (Int16)(_backingField & ~mask);
        }
    }

    private bool GetBitfield(Int16 mask)
    {
        return (_backingField & A1_MASK) != 0;
    }

    private const Int16 A1_MASK = 1 << 0;
    public bool a1
    {
        get { return GetBitfield(A1_MASK); }
        set { SetBitfield(A1_MASK, value); }
    }


    private const Int16 A2_MASK = 1 << 1;
    public bool a2
    {
        get { return GetBitfield(A2_MASK); }
        set { SetBitfield(A2_MASK, value); }
    }

    private const Int16 A3_MASK = 1 << 2;
    public bool a3
    {
        get { return GetBitfield(A3_MASK); }
        set { SetBitfield(A3_MASK, value); }
    }

    private const Int16 A4_MASK = 1 << 3;
    public bool a4
    {
        get { return GetBitfield(A4_MASK); }
        set { SetBitfield(A4_MASK, value); }
    }

    //And so on
}
```